# Beautifulsoup not returning TraderWagon HTML

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the HTML from TraderWagon? There's a lot of similar questions on SO and I've tried numerous ways to solve this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228558/beautifulsoup-not-extracting-all-html), , but none have worked.

**Attempt #1 - request + Beautifulsoup**

There should be `<table>` tags in the `doc` object, but there's none.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = "https://www.traderwagon.com/en/portfolio/156"
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

tableRows = doc.findAll(text="USDT")
print(tableRows)
```

**Attempt #2 - Selenium**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.traderwagon.com/en/portfolio/156"
#options = Options()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
container = soup.find_all('USDT')
print(container)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web page is completely dynamic and can't get the html in static way. Use `API` to extract data or use selenium to grab the dynamic content. You are getting empty `ResultSet` because the element selection isn't correct way. The following example `selenium with bs4` is working and producing the expected output.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.traderwagon.com/en/portfolio/156"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
for trs in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
    tr=list(trs.stripped_strings)
    print(tr)

#driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
['Symbol', 'Leverage | Direction', 'Size', 'Entry Price', 'Mark Price', 'Margin', 'PNL (ROE %)']
[]
['WAVESUSDT', '10X |', 'Short', '-79,639.86 USDT', '24.89 USDT', '4.00 USDT', '1,279.36 (Cross)', '66,846.27 USDT (5224.98%)']
['HNTUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-8,003.19 USDT', '11.43 USDT', '4.60 USDT', '798.66 (Cross)', '4,780.05 USDT (598.51%)']
['ETCUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-4,703.56 USDT', '47.04 USDT', '28.72 USDT', '143.62 (Cross)', '1,831.07 USDT (1274.90%)']
['TRXUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-31,684.99 USDT', '0.09 USDT', '0.06 USDT', '1,631.48 (Cross)', '9,405.30 USDT (576.49%)']
['STORJUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-2,760.00 USDT', '0.92 USDT', '0.47 USDT', '204.05 (Cross)', '1,343.98 USDT (658.65%)']
['SNXUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-11,961.99 USDT', '3.62 USDT', '2.49 USDT', '410.23 (Cross)', '3,757.41 USDT (915.93%)']
['KAVAUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-3,552.00 USDT', '2.96 USDT', '1.55 USDT', '93.10 (Cross)', '1,689.99 USDT (1815.24%)']
['RUNEUSDT', '5X |', 'Short', '-30,462.80 USDT', '8.23 USDT', '1.66 USDT', '1,228.50 (Cross)', '24,320.29 USDT (1979.67%)']
['APEUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-4,900.00 USDT', '24.50 USDT', '5.57 USDT', '55.72 (Cross)', '3,785.60 USDT (6793.97%)']
['BNXUSDT', '20X |', 'Short', '-67,123.04 USDT', '147.52 USDT', '158.59 USDT', '4,336.42 (Cross)', '-5,035.41 USDT (-116.12%)']
```